# Manual AKS PV fails with "New-SmbGlobalMapping MountVolume.SetUp failed for volume" error

Tags: kubernetes, azure-aks

I'm trying to mount an azureFile volume on a Windows AKS pod, but I get the error:

> kubelet, MountVolume.SetUp failed for volume "fileshare" :
>   New-SmbGlobalMapping failed: fork/exec
>   C:\windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe: The
>   parameter is incorrect., output: ""

My pod.yml looks like:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: q-pod-sample-03
  namespace: mq
spec:
  containers:
  - image: test.azurecr.io/q/p:01
    name: q-ctr-sample-03
    imagePullPolicy: "IfNotPresent"
    volumeMounts:
      - name: azfileshare
        mountPath: 'c:/app/app-data' 
  nodeSelector:
    "beta.kubernetes.io/os": windows
  volumes:
  - name: azfs
    azureFile:
      secretName: qastapv-share-01-secret
      shareName: qastapv-share-01
      readOnly: false
```

My secret.yml looks like:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: qastapv-share-01-secret
  namespace: mq
type: Opaque
data:
  azurestorageaccountname: <Base64Str>
  azurestorageaccountkey: <Base64Str>
```

My PV looks like:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: pv-azfs-q-01
  namespace: mq
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: 5Gi
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  azureFile:
    secretName: qastapv-share-01-secret
    shareName: qastapv-share-01
    readOnly: false
  mountOptions:
  - dir_mode=0777
  - file_mode=0777
  - uid=1000
  - gid=1000
```

What I'm missing here?
I'm on AKS 1.14.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I see, there is something wrong in your yaml file. First, in your pod yaml file:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: q-pod-sample-03
  namespace: mq
spec:
  containers:
  - image: test.azurecr.io/q/p:01
    name: q-ctr-sample-03
    imagePullPolicy: "IfNotPresent"
    volumeMounts:
      - name: azfileshare
        mountPath: 'c:/app/app-data' 
  nodeSelector:
    "beta.kubernetes.io/os": windows
  volumes:
  - name: azfileshare         # this name should be the same with the name in volumeMounts
    azureFile:
      secretName: qastapv-share-01-secret
      shareName: qastapv-share-01
      readOnly: false
```

And I do not know how do you convert the storage account name and the key into base64. So I also show two ways to create the secret in AKS.

One is to use the command to create as below:

```
kubectl create secret generic azure-secret --from-literal=azurestorageaccountname=$AKS_PERS_STORAGE_ACCOUNT_NAME --from-literal=azurestorageaccountkey=$STORAGE_KEY
```

Second is to use the yaml file and convert the storage account name and the key into base64 and input them in the yaml file as below:

```
echo 'storageAccountName' | base64
echo 'storageAccountKey' | base64
```

The yaml file as you show and input the output of the above commands.

Follow the above steps, you do not need to create the PV individual.

For more details, see [Manually create and use a volume with Azure Files share in Azure Kubernetes Service (AKS)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/azure-files-volume). And if you want to use the PV/PVC, take a look at [Mount volumes via PV and PVC](https://github.com/kubernetes/examples/tree/master/staging/volumes/azure_file#mount-volume-via-pv-and-pvc).

**Update:**

If you use the yaml file to create the secret, you also need to pay attention to the operating system where convert the string into base64. The different operating system may have different rules for the base64. For you, you use the Windows nodes, so you need to convert the storage account name and the key into base64 on the Windows system. Below is the PowerShell command to convert:

```
$Name= [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes("storageAccountName ")
[System.Convert]::ToBase64String($Name )
$Key = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes("storageAccountKey")
[System.Convert]::ToBase64String($Key)
```

Comment: Pod creation failed again :

**MountVolume.SetUp failed for volume "azfileshare" : New-SmbGlobalMapping failed: exit status 1, output: "New-SmbGlobalMapping : The parameter is incorrect. \r\nAt line:1 char:190\r\n+ ... ser, $PWord;New-SmbGlobalMapping -RemotePath $Env:smbremotepath -Cred ...\r\n+~~~~~~~~~~\r\n    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (MSFT_SmbGlobalMapping:ROOT/Microsoft/...mbGlobalMapping) [New-SmbGloba \r\n   lMapping], CimException\r\n    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Windows System Error 87,New-SmbGlobalMapping\r\n \r\n" **

Comment: If I create secret from cmdline then it works. But now different error:
**
Failed to pull image "test.azurecr.io/q/p:01": rpc error: code = Unknown desc = Error response from daemon: Get https://test.azurecr.io/v2/q/p/manifests/01: unauthorized: authentication required
**
I followed the steps as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-registry/container-registry-auth-aks#grant-aks-access-to-acr)

Comment: @Sam This is a normal error. You can check if you use a wrong image. You also need to check in the ACR if the AKS is allowed in its access control.

Comment: @Sam I update the answer for using yaml file to create secret. The error you got dues to the operating system.

Comment: I didn't realize that i need to convert both key and name. but now it works like a charm. Thanks!